# python txt file while stop

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm looking for how to stop a while by condition. stop in $ config1 work.
how to stop into the first ! after node $ config1 ?

```
def filtre(source):
fs = open(source, 'r')
while 1:
    txt = fs.readline()
    if txt =='':
        break

    else:
        print txt
        if txt == "$ config1\n":
            raw_input("==========================>")

            if txt == "!\n":
               raw_input("==========================>") 

fs.close()
return
```

txt file

```
! ************************************
! *  Export File:  X:\test.txt
! *      Created by:  PC2
! *   Creation Date:  10/01/2014 18:50
! *            User:  test
! *************************************
!
!
$ config1
MCBR:54:62:2:32:.5:x34:y637::::
MCBR:54:62:2:32:.5:x34:y637::::
MCBR:54:62:2:32:.5:x34:y637::::
MCBR:54:62:2:32:.5:x34:y637::::
!
!
$ End of file.
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And your question is not very clear

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop on the file object? `for line in file` is the usual way to iterate over the lines in a file, and it's much simpler than doing lots of `readline` calls.

Comment: Your code already stops in both lines "$ config1\n" and "!\n". What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, this code work, :)

```
def filtre(source):
fs = open(source, 'r')
started = false
while 1:
    txt = fs.readline()
    if txt =='':
        break

    else:
        print txt
        if txt == "$ config1\n":
            started = true
            raw_input("==========================>")

            if started and txt == "!\n":
               break 

fs.close()
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You nested one of the `if` statements inside another, and I don't think you intended to.

"if, else if" in Python can be written like:

```
if condition1:
    reaction1
elif condition2:
    reaction2
```

or

```
if condition1:
    reaction1
else:
    if condition2:
        reaction2
```

Or, if you know that `condition1` and `condition2` can't happen at the same time, this does the same thing:

```
if condition1:
    reaction1
if condition2:
    reaction2
```

The level of indenting is important.

Comment: `def filtre(source):
fs = open(source, 'r')
started = false
while 1:
    txt = fs.readline()
    if txt =='':
        break

    else:
        print txt
        if txt == "$ config1\n":
            started = true
            raw_input("==========================>")

            if started and txt == "!\n":
               break 

fs.close()
return`